# Removing 1x shadow line under Segmented Pager in CarbonKit

Tags: objective-c, carbonkit

I am using CarbonKit in my project as a segmented pager. I am trying to remove 1px shadow line under the tool but I am not able to do it. I used this code but didn't help.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

I am wondering how to delete this 1px shadow line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by this

```
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.clipsToBounds = true
```